# Lightroom publish only flagged photos in collection-set while maintaining structure

Tags: lightroom, lightroom-catalog, publishing, smart-collections

I'm trying to publish *only the flagged* photos from a collection-set to my local disk in a folder hierarchy that mimics the collection hierarchy you build within Lightroom.

I am aware of *"Jeffrey’s “Collection Publisher” Lightroom Plugin"*, in fact the description of what I want to do is partially copied from his site. But if I'm not mistaken, it isn't possible to apply rules to the mirrored collection(-sets).

Of course I am aware it is possible to manually create new collections without the flagged photos in them. This would require me to recreate all my current collections, and I would have to manually keep the new collections up to date in the flagged only versions.

I could also create a normal collection-set in Jeffrey's collection publisher plugin and create smart collections for each "normal" collection and filter all non-flagged photos by adding rules. But this also would mean I need to create a new smart collection every time I create a new "normal" collection.

I've previously been using the "Folder publisher" plugin, in which I select a root directory to publish and filter non-flagged photos by adding a rule. The main advantage of this setup was I didn't need to do anything multiple times. I could just make adjustments to my photos and click publish and be done.

Am I perhaps missing something in the “Collection Publisher” plugin, or does anyone have some other methods of doing this?

Comment: Do you want to do this in a single click of a button when the collection is selected/open, or a 2-3 steps process would also do it?

Comment: I would prefer a one click solution like I had with the Folder Publisher, but if there is no other way... Needing to create new (smart)collections every time is a bridge to far tho. What do you suggest?

Comment: After reading your first sentence, I'm already confused!

Answer (score 1):

You can set the Attribute Filter on Flagged
[image: Lightroom Filter only Flagged]

Then select all pictures, click right and Export

Comment: When doing this I wont have the collection-structure as a folder structure after export. Adding this filter before publishing via the collection publish plugin doesn't mean the unflagged photos are not published.